# Azure Schema Extensions in Graph Client

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Whatever I tried I cannot set an extension property on a User object, here is a reproducible piece of code:

```
public async Task CleanTest(string extName)
      {
         ExtensionProperty ep = new ExtensionProperty
         {
            Name = extName,
            DataType = "String",
            TargetObjects = { "User" }
         };

         App app = (App)(await _client.Applications.Where(a => a.AppId == _managementAppClientId).ExecuteSingleAsync());
         app.ExtensionProperties.Add(ep);
         await app.UpdateAsync();

         GraphUser user = (GraphUser)(await _client.Users.Where(u => u.UserPrincipalName.Equals("email")).ExecuteSingleAsync());
         string propName = FormatExtensionPropertyName(extName); //formats properly as extesion_xxx_name
         user.SetExtendedProperty(propName, "testvalue");
         //user.SetExtendedProperty(extName, "testvalue");
         await user.UpdateAsync(); // fails here
      }
```

user.UpdateAsync() according to Fiddler doesn't even go out and application fails with an exception:

"The property 'extension_e206e28ff36244b19bc56c01160b9cf0_UserEEEqdbtgd3ixx2' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Internal.User'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."

Answer (score 2):

This issue is also being tracked here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/issues/28

I've got an alternative workaround for this bug, for those that want to use the version 5.7 OData libraries rather than redirecting to the v5.6.4 versions.

Add a request pipeline configuration handler.

```
// initialize in the usual way
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = 
  AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
// after initialization add a handler to the request pipline configuration.
activeDirectoryClient.Context
  .Configurations.RequestPipeline
  .OnMessageWriterSettingsCreated(UndeclaredPropertyHandler);
```

In the handler, change the ODataUndeclaredPropertyBehaviorKinds value on the writer settings to SupportUndeclaredValueProperty.

```
private static void UndeclaredPropertyHandler(MessageWriterSettingsArgs args)
{
  var field = args.Settings.GetType().GetField("settings", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
  var settingsObject = field?.GetValue(args.Settings);
  var settings = settingsObject as ODataMessageWriterSettings;
  if (settings != null)
  {
    settings.UndeclaredPropertyBehaviorKinds = 
       ODataUndeclaredPropertyBehaviorKinds.SupportUndeclaredValueProperty;
  }
}
```

Comment: Although useful, this is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you still looking for solution to this problem or someone else is facing the same issue:

I got similar issue and it looks like, at least for me, the problem was in latest version of "Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" package - 5.7.0 (or in one of it dependencies). When I downgraded to previous version - 5.6.4 it worked as a charm.

I had same symptoms - updating of extended property was failing even w/o any request is made (also used Fiddler)

Hope it helps!

Artem Liman

Comment: Great, I have to try it today. Is Microsoft aware of this issue? )

Comment: Seems like other folks are tracking the issue [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/issues/28).